# Problems with cudaMalloc and "out of memory" error

Tags: c++, cuda

Are there any restrictions for allocating device memory despite not exceeding available memory?
I get following error after trying to allocate 64MB:

```
cudaSafeCall() Runtime API error : out of memory.
```

However, according to **cuMemGetInfo** there is over 200MB left.

Here is scenario:

```
size_t size = 4096 * 4096 * sizeof (float);
cuMemGetInfo(&fr, &ttl); // fr indicates 284 MB
cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**) &tmp, size));
p1 = tmp;
cuMemGetInfo(&fr, &ttl); // fr indicates 220 MB
cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**) &tmp, size)); // this fails !!!
p2 = tmp;
```

What am I missing?

I am using:

```
Cuda compilation tools, release 3.2, V0.2.1221
NVidia Driver 260.19.26
Linux(Slackware) x86
```

Update:

This behavior is quite non-deterministic. From time to time above case succeeds and I get correct results, without any error.

Comment: Memory fragmentation? Can you allocate two blocks of 32 MB, or four blocks of 16 MB, or...?

Comment: You are probably right sir. I was able to achieve level of 8MB free memory allocating 300 * 1MB blocks. Please convert your comment to answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas pointed out the problem is memory fragmentation. (Confirmed by experiment. I didn't find reliable source to link)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reallocating the same memory, as you are reusing tmp. If you are used to Object Oriented code, you are likely mistaking pointer with references to objects.

The following code should give you the same result:

```
size_t size = 4096 * 4096 * sizeof(float);
float* p1;
float* p2;
cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**) &p1, size));
cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**) &p2, size));
```

Comment: Yes, same result but I don't understand what you mean by 'reallocating same memory'. I think that you missed the point here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same memory pointer to allocate memory twice. I know that you are using **p1** to backup the first memory allocation address, but you are forgetting to clear **tmp** after that. Maybe `cudaMalloc()` is failing because of it. It's just a wild guess.

```
size_t size = 4096 * 4096 * sizeof (float);
cuMemGetInfo(&fr, &ttl); 
cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**) &tmp, size));
p1 = tmp;
tmp = 0; // or NULL to clear the pointer
cuMemGetInfo(&fr, &ttl); 
cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**) &tmp, size));
p2 = tmp;
```

Comment: No change :-( But I've noticed new symptom (question updated).